# Is non-causal, non-LTI solution to difference equation correct?

Tags: discrete-signals, finite-differences, differential-equation

**Find a solution to the difference equation $y[n]-\frac{5}{6}y[n-1]+\frac{1}{6}y[n-2]=\frac{1}{3}x[n-1]$ that is neither casual nor LTI, where $y[0]=y[1]=1$ and $x[n]=\delta[n]$**

The homogenous solution for the difference equation is

$$y_h[n] =A_1(\frac{1}{2})^n + A_2(\frac{1}{3})^n$$

Solving for specific solution ($y_h[0]=y_h[1]=1$):

\begin{equation}
y_1[n]=4(\frac{1}{2})^n-3(\frac{1}{3})^n \tag{1}
\end{equation}

We want to "modify" $y_1[1]$ or $y_1[0]$ or $y_1[-1]$ because the right hand side of the difference equation is non-zero at $n=1$.

Since $y[1]$ and $y[0]$ are specifically set to $1$ in the question, we must change $y[-1]$.

$$y[1]-\frac{5}{6}y[0]+\frac{1}{6}y[-1]=\frac{1}{3}x[0]$$
$$1-\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1}{6}y[-1]=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$y[-1]=1$$

Since $y_1[-1]=-1$, $y_1$ will be the correct output *only for $n \geq 0$*. This means that we need to find another "piece" $y_2$ for $n < 0$ such that $y_2[0]=y_1[0]$.

Solving another specific solution with $y_h[-1]=y_h[0]=1$:

\begin{equation}
y_2[n]=2(\frac{1}{2})^n-(\frac{1}{3})^n \tag 2
\end{equation}

Hence, our solution is:

$$
y[n] = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
       4(\frac{1}{2})^n-3(\frac{1}{3})^n & n\geq 0 \\
      2(\frac{1}{2})^n-(\frac{1}{3})^n & n \lt 0 \\
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

which can be written as

$$y[n]=4(\frac{1}{2})^n-3(\frac{1}{3})^n-2(\frac{1}{2})^nu[-n-1]+2(\frac{1}{3})^nu[-n-1]$$

---

Is there a faster way to approach this problem (possibly using Fourier transform)? How would you solve this for complicated inputs, e.g. $x[n]=u[n]$?

Comment: In what way is that nonlinear?  In what way is it time varying?

Comment: @TimWescott The input $x[n] = \delta[n] = 0$ for $n < 0$; however, $y[n] \ne 0$ for $n < 0$. That means the solution is not linear.

Comment: @TimWescott I think the use of $u[-n-1]$ makes it time varying. If input is delayed by 1, then the coefficient $u[-n-1]$ will not be delayed. I'm not sure if I'm right on this one, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's not causal, but that doesn't mean it's not LTI.

Comment: Typically when you have a system that's described by linear difference equations and has non-zero initial values, you say it's linear with non-zero initial values, or linear with boundary conditions.  As long as you take those initial values to be inputs, then the system obeys superposition.  Similarly, the system description *itself* is time invariant -- the fact that you've got a $u [ -n - 1]$ term in the *solution* doesn't make the *system* time varying.

Comment: @TimWescott I see what you're saying. This solution is non-causal but not necessarily non-LTI. Feel free to write an answer. This question is from Oppenheim's book on Discrete Signal Processing (chapter 1)

Comment: @TimWescott Can this system be called non-LTI because of the constraints - $y[0] = y[1] = 1$, no matter how much you scale the input $x[n]$.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.  It's kind of a gray area -- is the *system* forcing the constraints $y[0] = y[1] = 1$, or is that part of the problem statement?  If the system is somehow magically forcing that, then it is indeed time-varying and nonlinear.  Normally when you see a problem in a book with constraints like that, it's because someone is trying to determine the system behavior under a certain set of circumstances, and the system itself is linear.